# How can i do performance counting in Java SE on Windows and Linux?

Tags: java

how can i do performance counting in Java SE on Windows and Linux?

How are people do this? I want to monitor messages/events per second etc

Thanks

Comment: or take a look at jvisualvm, it sits in your java bin directory and can monitor/find hotspots in running applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance counters are no different to other counters.  You increment a number and every so often, you divide this number by the time elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

basically (this is made simple and just for one thread in mind):
1.)start timer
have a private counter
2.)increment every time something happens
3.)after one second passed display the number in the counter
4.)reset the counter
5.)Go to step 1.)